# Is it possible to configure sublime text to autocomplete for an installed package?

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 and already have anaconda installed. My question is if I install a package is their an autocomplete that goes out and searches for the modules of that package. I have noticed that anaconda has the basic datetime modules and such but I am using appJar which has a ton of CamelCase stuff I am just getting bogged down. I guess there are two options:

1. Is there an autocomplete that can be pointed at documentation to create its library.
2. Is there an autocomplete that has appJars modules.

Is there something better out there then anaconda?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With the caveat that I don't use it and so can't say for sure, it's possible that the Jedi package might help here. It looks like you have to tell it where python modules are, but it will look for them and pull them in. Might be worth a peek: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jedi%20-%20Python%20autocompletion